# some confusion in uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f(x) =x^2  $ is uniformly continuous  on $[0,1]$?

My attempt :

$$x_n:=\sqrt n\implies |x_{n+1}-x_n|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;,\;\;\text{yet nevertheless}\;\;|f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)|\rlap{\;\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

so $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $ [0,1]$

Is its true ?

Comment: $x_n\notin[0,1]$ for $n\ge2$.

Comment: Continuous functions on compact sets are always uniformly continuous.

Comment: $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^2-y^2|=|(x+y)(x-y)| \leq 2 |x-y|$$ so pick $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and hence result follows!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR thanks u

Comment: @ChinnapparajR sir can u suggest  me   I  got  AIR - 567 ranks   GATE -2019 exam    did  IIT bombay  will call  me for  interview ??? .i have  filled IIT madars  but they  didn't shortlisted   ..Nowdays im becoming very frustrated  i  could not able clear CSIR NET exam   i don't know  what to do now

Comment: @jasmine: See my answer !. Try to note the list of institutes. I delete it after you see, because it includes in the answer box, so others may not agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^2-y^2|=|(x+y)(x-y)|\leq2|x-y| $$So pick $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

In general, for any $[a,b]$, we can always find a bound for $x+y$, but this is not the case for $\Bbb R$. For sequential criterion for non-uniform continuity of $x^2$ on $\Bbb R$, observe that $$|n-(n+1/n)| \to 0\;\text{but}\;|f(n)-f(n+1/n)| \;\text{is not}$$

Comment: thanks u so much @Chinnapparaj  R  sir   i will try  my best for coming  june  csir 2019  exam

Comment: oh sad i missed CMI